# Perform operation on pandas sparse data type without changing the fill value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I currently have a sparse dataframe in this form:

```
df = [[True, False , False],
      [False, False, True],
      [False, True, False]]
```

The data type of each column is Sparse[bool, False]. I want to obtain the reverse of it, that is True -> False and False -> True while keeping the data type of each column to be Sparse[bool, False].

I have tried using the '~' operator, the value did changed, but the data type also changed to Sparse[bool, True]. Is there any way to fix this?

UPDATE: I'm trying to concatenate the two matrices together, and I realized that doing so would just result in a sparse matrix with the same memory usage as a dense matrix, so there's no point in trying to keep it sparse through out.

Comment: The described behaviour seems reasonable in that it results in the most compression. What is the benefit of your required change?

Comment: So you want a whole new sparse series, with all the 'fill' elements turned into `True`, and the nonzero `True` turned into `False` fills.  You might as well flip the dense version.  Sparse changes are  most efficient if the location of the nonzero terms doesn't change.

Comment: @user19077881 I'm going to concatenate the two dataframes and then run df.to_coo(), which requires the fill value through out the dataframe to be 0 or False.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy where to replace the values.

```
df = [[True, False , False],
      [False, False, True],
      [False, True, False]]

original_array = np.array(df)
remade_array = np.where(original_array, False, True)
```

The end result

```
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

Comment: This creates a dense array in progress though, and I want to keep the sparse format through out the process.